# How to declare an external cuda function template in C++

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have a little problems with some CUDA functions.

I want to separate the `.cu` file from an Nvidia sample in a `.cu` file and a `.cpp` file. The kernel is a function template. I'm getting an error when I declare it as an external function in the C++ file.

The definition looks like this:

```
template <int BLOCK_SIZE> __global__ void
matrixMulCUDA(float *C, float *A, float *B, int wA, int wB)
```

And I have declare the function in C++ like this:

```
template <int BLOCK_SIZE> extern void 
matrixMulCUDA(float *C, float *A, float *B, int wA, int wB);
```

The declaration doesn't give me any errors but when it's used like this:

```
if (block_size == 16)
    {
        matrixMulCUDA <16> << < grid, threads >> >(d_C, d_A, d_B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
    }
    else
    {
        matrixMulCUDA <32> << < grid, threads >> >(d_C, d_A, d_B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
    }
```

It tells me "syntax error '<'".

Can someone tell me how I should declare the function in C++? Note that when everything is put in the `.cu` file it runs ok.

Comment: Please explain, what `<< < grid, threads >> >` should mean in your usage of `matrixMulCuda`.

Comment: Is the "used like this" code in the `.cu` file, or the `.cpp` file?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius It's CUDA kernel invocation syntax (with a weird space inserted).

Comment: @Angew , code is from CUDA sample.

Comment: @Adi OK, but after you've split the file, is the code in the `.cu` file or the `.cpp` file?

Comment: The kernel is in the .cu file and the rest of the code in the .cpp file. Only the kernel is in the .cu file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not too specific about it, but it seems the kernel invocation call (the code shown in the question) is in the `.cpp` file, not in the `.cu` file.

If that's the case, then that is indeed the problem. The CUDA kernel-launching syntax of `name <<<dims>>> (args)` is a syntactic construct of NVCC, not of host C++ compilers. Any code which uses it must therefore be processed by NVCC, which normally translates to being in a `.cu` file instead of plain `.cpp`.

You'll have to move the kernel-invoking code into a `.cu` file. Normally, you could easily wrap it in a pure C++ function declared in a C++ header and defined in the `.cu` file. With templates, this is not so easy; you'll have to move the whole `if` block there. So something like this:

**Shared header file**

```
void callMatrixMulKernel(std::size_t block_size, float *C, float *A, float *B, int wA, int wB);
```

**`.cu` file**

```
void callMatrixMulKernel(std::size_t block_size, float *C, float *A, float *B, int wA, int wB)
{
  if (block_size == 16)
  {
    matrixMulCUDA <16> <<< grid, threads >>>(d_C, d_A, d_B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
  }
  else
  {
    matrixMulCUDA <32> <<< grid, threads >>>(d_C, d_A, d_B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
  }
}
```

**`.cpp` file**

```
// In some function somewhere
callMatrixMulKernel(16, d_C, d_A, d_B, dimsA.x, dimsB.x);
```